# A function on binary relations

Tags: functions, relations, galois-connections

Let $\rho$ is a function mapping every binary relation $f$ (on some set $U$) into a function which maps binary relations into binary relations by the formula

$$(\rho(f))(g) = f\circ g.$$

Is $\rho$:

1. upper adjoint in a Galois connection?
2. lower adjoint in a Galois connection?
3. meet-semilattice homomorphisms?
4. join-semilattice homomorphisms?

(The order assumed is the set-theoretic inclusion of binary relations.)

If it has adjoints, what these adjoints are?

Comment: That $\rho$ is a lower adjoint is obvious (take $\rho$ on a union of a set of binary relations). I yet don't know what is its upper adjoint, however.

Comment: Now most of my question is solved, but there is lack for an explicit formula of the upper adjoint to $\rho$

Answer (score 1):

For various reasons (probably largely to do with issues of variance), it's a little tricky interpreting the question. There is a classical notion of Galois connection which involves a pair of *contravariant* poset maps

$$\phi: P(X) \to P(Y), \qquad \psi: P(Y) \to P(X)$$

such that $A \leq \psi(\phi(A))$ for all $A \in P(X)$ and $B \leq \phi(\psi(B))$ for all $B \in P(Y)$. There is also a more general notion of Galois connection between posets, not just power sets, and is basically the notion of "pair of adjoint functors between posets", in other words *covariant* functors between posets $\phi: P^{op} \to Q$ and $\psi: Q \to P^{op}$ such that $\psi \dashv \phi$.)

I'll go with the second meaning. I assume the set of functions from binary relations to binary relations $\hom(P(X \times X), P(X \times X))$ is given the "pointwise" order, where $f \leq g$ means $f(A) \leq g(A)$ in $P(X \times X)$ for all $A \in P(X \times X)$, taking $\leq$ to be the usual inclusion order on $P(X \times X)$.

Then the *covariant* map $\phi: P(X \times X) \to \hom(P(X \times X), P(X \times X))$ in the question seems to take a relation $R$ to the function $S \mapsto R \circ S$, also denoted $\lambda S. R \circ S$. Then, as I think porton is surmising, $\phi$ is indeed a left adjoint. One way of demonstrating that is via the adjoint functor theorem for functors between complete posets: that a functor in this case is a left adjoint if and only if it preserves arbitrary joins = unions.

To prove that $R \mapsto \lambda S. R \circ S$ preserves unions, we just check this pointwise, i.e., that for each $S$ the map $R \mapsto R \circ S$ preserves unions. And indeed it does. That in part is what porton is verifying in his answer.

My own preferred proof is direct. Observe the functor $- \circ S: P(X \times X) \to P(X \times X)$ has a right adjoint, namely the map $S \Rightarrow (-): P(X \times X) \to P(X \times X)$ defined by

$$P(X \times X) \ni T \mapsto \{(x, y): \forall_z \; y S z \Rightarrow x T z\}.$$

The adjunction just says

$$\exists_y \; x R y \; \wedge\; y S z \Rightarrow x T z\;\;\; \text{iff}\;\;\; x R y \Rightarrow \forall_z \; y S z \Rightarrow x T z$$

which is obviously the case. Now we calculate, for all $f \in \hom(P(X \times X), P(X \times X))$,

$$\lambda S. R \circ S \leq f \;\; \text{iff}\;\; \forall_S \; R \circ S \leq f(S) \;\;\text{iff}\;\; \forall_S \; R \leq S \Rightarrow f(S) \;\;\text{iff}\;\; R \leq \bigcap_{S: P(X \times X)} S \Rightarrow f(S);$$

this shows directly that $R \mapsto \lambda S. R \circ S$ is a left adjoint.

But it is not a right adjoint; indeed, it does not preserve arbitrary meets. This boils down to saying that there are $S$ such that $- \circ S$ does not preserve arbitrary meets, so porton's second proposition is false. It doesn't even preserve binary meets. It is true for $S$ atomic (so porton's lemma is okay); this is actually a nice fact, that composing with an atomic relation preserves arbitrary meets. But not for general $S$.

For a specific example, consider a set with four elements $u, v, v', w$. Let $R$ be the atomic relation $\{(u, v)\}$, let $R'$ be the atomic relation $\{(u, v')\}$, and let $S$ be the relation $\{(v, w), (v', w)\}$. Then $(R \wedge R') \circ S$ is the empty relation (there is no $(x, z)$ such that $\exists_y x R y \wedge x R' y \wedge y S z$), whereas we do have $u R \circ S w$ and $u R' \circ S w$. Hence the statement

$$(R \circ S) \wedge (R' \circ S) \leq (R \wedge R') \circ S$$

is false in this example. (I suspect the problem is that porton was misapplying the distributivity of meets over unions.)

Answer (score 0):

Let $F$ is a set of binary relations and $A$ is a binary relation.

**Proposition**
  $\left( \bigcup F \right) \circ A = \bigcup \left\{ f \circ A \,|\, f \in F \right\}$.

**Proof**
  $( x ; z) \in \left( \bigcup F \right) \circ A \Leftrightarrow \exists y :
  \left( ( x ; y) \in A \wedge ( y ; z) \in \bigcup F \right) \Leftrightarrow
  \exists y : ( ( x ; y) \in A \wedge \exists f \in F : ( y ; z) \in f)
  \Leftrightarrow \exists y, f \in F : ( ( x ; y) \in A \wedge ( y ; z) \in f)
  \Leftrightarrow \exists f \in F \exists y : ( ( x ; y) \in A \wedge ( y ; z)
  \in f) \Leftrightarrow \exists f \in F : ( x ; z) \in f \circ A
  \Leftrightarrow ( x ; z) \in \bigcup \left\{ f \circ A \,|\, f \in F \right\}$.

**Proposition**
  $\left( \bigcap F \right) \circ a = \bigcap \left\{ f \circ a \,|\, f \in F \right\}$ if $a$ is a singleton binary relation.

**Proof**
  Let $a = \{ ( a_0 ; a_1) \}$.

$( x ; z) \in \left( \bigcap F \right) \circ a \Leftrightarrow x = a_0
  \wedge ( a_1 ; z) \in \bigcap F \Leftrightarrow x = a_0 \wedge \forall f \in
  F : ( a_1 ; z) \in f \Leftrightarrow \forall f \in F : ( x = a_0 \wedge (
  a_1 ; z) \in f) \Leftrightarrow \forall f \in F : ( x ; z) \in f \circ a
  \Leftrightarrow ( x ; z) \in \bigcap \left\{ f \circ a \,|\, f \in F \right\}$.

**Proposition** (wrong)
  $\left( \bigcap F \right) \circ A = \bigcap \left\{ f \circ A \,|\, f \in F \right\}$.

This proposition fails with the following counter-example. It seems that in the proof I have misused the law of complete distributivity.

$A = \{(4,2),(4,3)\}$; $f_1 = \{(2,1)\}$; $f_2 = \{(3,1)\}$; $F=\{f_1,f_2\}$.

Then $(\bigcap F) \circ A = \varnothing$ but $\bigcap \{f \circ A \,|\, f\in F\} = \{(4,1)\}$.

As a consequence from the above we have:

$\rho \bigcup F = \bigcup \rho [F]$,
that is $\rho$ has upper adjoint.

From
$\left( \bigcap F \right) \circ a = \bigcap \left\{ f \circ a \,|\, f \in F \right\}$
it follows that $\rho$ has a lower adjoint, because to specify $\rho$ it is enough to specify it on singleton relations.

The remaining problem is to write explicit formulas for lower and upper adjoint of $\rho$.

I don't specify our ``universal sets'' in the below formula for simplicity.
You can easily correct this omission if you want to be formal.

The upper adjoint is $b \mapsto \max \left\{ x \, | \,
\forall a : x \circ a \subseteq b [ a] \right\}$.

The lower adjoint is $b \mapsto \min \left\{ x \, | \,
\forall a : x \circ a \supseteq b [ a] \right\}$.

Can these formulas be simplified?

Comment: Oops, a conceptual error: From $\left( \bigcap F \right) \circ a \ne \bigcap \left\{ f \circ a \,|\, f \in F \right\}$ it does not follow that $\rho$ is not an upper adjoint

Comment: I've rewritten my answer. Now it says that there are both lower and upper adjoints. The explicit formulas for the adjoints are however lacking